# Mysql Query to pull latest 5 searches from table

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the table structure:

[image: table structure]

I want to pull last 5 unique domain.

I have tried following query, but it shows incorrect results - it wipes google.com from results since it also exist against prior ids:
`SELECT DISTINCT domain FROM searches ORDER BY id DESC 5`

Can anyone suggest a fix to the query.

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5`

Comment: Post your data as text and not image.

Comment: If the same domain can have different ids - which id do you want to use for ORDER BY?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT domain  
FROM your_table_name  
ORDER BY domain_id DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

This will get the required output!!!

Comment: This is invalid with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode.

Comment: I say: bad idea - fix query.

Comment: Oh Got you, any other alternative?

Comment: Sure.. but first the question must be clarified.

Comment: Yeah waiting for the same, once clarified I will update my answer

Comment: "This is invalid with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode." @PaulSpiegel  having fun with optimizer/exection differences in MySQL??  [MySQL 5.5 / 5.6 executes](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEkxRy33u7Xp5wEE3pqZCC/0) and more modern versions [MySQL 5.7 / 8 errors](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jEkxRy33u7Xp5wEE3pqZCC/1) like expected, this is how applications break... The why is explained here [DISTINCT Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html) which happen in the optimizer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland I see it as bug in 5.5 and 5.6. An [equivalent GROUP BY query](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3WDWxgqRUa6xwB5eqKYww5/0) fails in 5.6 and still runs in 5.5. It should make no difference if it's GROUP BY or DISTINCT, SELECT or ORDER BY - `domain_id` is just **not defined** in this query.

Comment: "It should make no difference if it's GROUP BY or DISTINCT, SELECT or ORDER BY - domain_id is just not defined in this query." Yes @PaulSpiegel i very much agree you on that one don't get me wrong.. The article i documentation i linked explains DISTINCT might be handled like a "special" `GROUP BY` so it would only make sense `DISTINCT` needs to be valid like `GROUP BY` and needs to define all non aggreged columns (if that's even a valid term for a DISTINCT query most likely not)

Comment: Incorrect - this query is exactly what i mentioned in my question and notified this doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `GROUP BY`:

```
select domain, max(search_at)
from t
group by domain
order by max(search_at) desc;
```

This presumes that by "latest" you mean based on the `search_at` column.  You can do the same thing with the `id`, if that is how you define "latest".

Also, you do not need to include `max(search_at)` in the `select`.  I put it in because you might be interested in that.